# VirtualBox networking OSX Host and BackTrack Guest

Tags: macos, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, backtrack

Does anybody know how to get networking working on a VM BackTrack OS?
Im using a Mobile broadband USB Dongle in my OSX and i want that connection to be shared to my linux VM also.
when i check the connected USB devices from the VM,it is showing as disabled.

What you guys think i should do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to bridge the host-only network device with your USB device. Then give your linux VM an IP and add the gateway of your USB device to your routing table. It is likely that the USB device requires USB 2.0, which might not be supported (lack of driver) in the VM (at least that was a message that I've seen before).